# Guidance on creating a scalable web service

Tags: json, web-services, nginx

I'm looking for tips on ways to implement a web service that performs a simple lookup operation:

- accepts a POST request containing some JSON in the request body
- looks up some static data from a couple of text files
- sends back a JSON response based on the data looked up
- is able to handle ~10K requests/s

I was thinking of using nginx and coding the lookup functionality as a C++ module. Is this a good approach or is there a more lightweight solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx will be able to handle the load because it is efficient as it uses Multiplexing with non blocking I/O. This means, it won't fork a process for each request, like Apache does. You should look into getting a machine with a fast CPU, and a lot of network bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks, those are good tips. About nginx being better than Apache (when using pre-fork MPM), yes agree completely. In fact, what I'm trying to do here is improve on an existing prototype that implements this web service using Apache + fastcgi + perl. The perl script is slow and dragging down performance (the max I could achieve so far is on the order of 500 req/s on a i5 with 8GB of ram).

So, do you reckon Nginx with custom C++ module would be a good replacement for Apache with Perl back end for doing this simple lookup from text files? Thanks

Comment: Based on what I've learnt so far I guess this comes closest to answering my question.  Just wondering if there's any alternatives out there that might be better in some way than doing an nginx + custom module?

Comment: I know nginx has an API, but you'd have to measure weather that would be faster than using FastCGI. I'm not sure I can answer that part